# PHP parse URL filename

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing, url

Using the following I am able to parse a url and get the filename.

```
  $path_parts = pathinfo($url);
  echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; 
  $result=$path_parts['filename'];
```

I am trying to save the $result to a file but keep getting "Trying to get property of non-object". I believe I understand $result is an array and I am trying to save it as a string so am I am getting this error, just don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: No, that bit by itself is not an array. Show us how you're trying to save the result. "Property of a non-object" points to something else entirely.

Comment: $resultText= $xml->createTextNode($result->nodeValue);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for the current file you could use:

```
$filename = __FILE__;
$queries = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$strurl = $filename . "?=" . $queries;
```

Answer (score 0):

After much research I have discovered how to parse the filename and pass to xml without the error message.

```
    $xml->createtextNode($path_parts['filename']);
```

where $path_parts=pathinfo($url). I initially was passing it as I show but had

```
    $xml->createtextNode($path_parts['filename']->nodeValue);
```

removing ->nodeValue fixed problem.